# Ossim multiple extra_data

Tags: intrusion-detection

Piece of my log:

> Info1: attack multiple Activity_ID: 0 activity_Name: name_activity

My decoder (not complete)

```
<decoder name="my-log">
  <parent>parent</parent>
  <regex offset="after_parent">^ Info1: (\S+) (\S+) Activity_ID: (\S+) activity_Name: (\S+)</regex>
  <order> extra_data, extra_data , id, extra_data</order>
</decoder>
```

In rules, I want search in different extra_data, for example.
if extra_data1 ^attack 
if extra_data2 ^multiple
if extra_data3 ^name

Is it possible apply expression regular in multiple extra_data?
Thanks